# Function independent of the order of variables?

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have a function **Refraction**:

```
def Refraction(n_i, n_j, theta_i):        
    theta_j = arcsin(n_i/n_j * sin(theta_i)    
    return theta_j
```

Now if I change the position of arguments, like this:

```
Refraction(theta_1,n1,n2)
```

It will give a different result than what the function meant to be.

Now my question would be that is there any way to define a function that is independent of the order of the variables? so that I can recall the function inside another function that takes the same variables in different order, for an example:

```
def Fresnel(theta_i, n_i, n_j):

    # call the function
    theta_j = Refraction(theta_i, n_i, n_j)

    rs_ij = ni*cos(theta_i) - n_j*cos(theta_j) / (n_i*cos(theta_i) +   n_j*cos(theta_j))

    return rs_ij
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or critics.

Comment: So if your function is called with `Refraction(1,2,3)`, how should the function deduce which parameter is supposed to to correspond to each argument?

Comment: there is a mistake in the terms I used, sorry for that, I mean the variables, when I call the function, I should give arguments to variables in such an order  how  I define them in the function. the question is now how I could preserve the property of the function if I change the position of the variables when I call it inside another function which takes same variables with different order, lets take an example,'  def Fresnel(theta_i, n_i, n_j):  '

Comment: The function does not receive the variables used in the expression that called it. It only receives the **values** from those variables. Either you need to put those arguments in a consistent order, or you need to used named parameters as the answers suggest. The function cannot know what order you meant the arguments to be used by magic.

Comment: You are right, I tried that before and it does not work if I changed the order other than what I defined in the function. But I am just curious about know the possibility to do that in python. thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can name your arguments when calling the function. Then, the order won't matter as long as the arguments are named.

```
Refraction(n_i=n1, n_j=n2, theta_i=theta_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use named arguments (like AnisR suggested) or change the parameter into
a dict that holds values by name. This will be useful if you want to add
arguments later and make them optional for existing calls.